# JBoss EAR deployment order

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss7.x, maven-3, maven-ear-plugin

I have 5 EARs that need to be deployed. One of them, `local-configuration-ear-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT.ear`, is a dependency of all the others, and they require it at deployment time, i.e. `local-configuration-ear-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT.ear` needs to be deployed first. All 5 of the EARs are located in the `deployments` folder.

I read [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-as-7-deployment-order) that I can use `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to manage the order of EAR deployment, but I ran into some issues.
The file I made looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="deployment.local-configuration-ear-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT.ear" />
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

but after deploying the EAR with this descriptor, I received the following error:

```
15:01:29,752 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.asterix-connector-ear-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT.ear".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in s ervice jboss.module.service."deployment.asterix-connector-ear-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT.ear".main: Failed to load module: deployment.asterix-connector-ear-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT.ear:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: deployment.local-configuration-ear-0.3.5-SNAPSHOT:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:854)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1181)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relink(Module.java:1211)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.relink(ModuleLoader.java:445)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ServiceModuleLoader.relinkModule(ServiceModuleLoader.java:204) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:71) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to generate `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` using Maven so that I can append a version number to my EAR file name programatically?

**EDIT**:

I also tried adding a `jboss-all.xml` file to `META-INF`, but it didn't help:

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="local-configuration-ear-${project.version}.ear" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

-with `<filtering>true</filtering>` in the `maven-ear-plugin` configuration. I checked inside the EAR archive, and the project version is set correctly, but the artefacts are still sometimes deployed in the incorrect order.

Answer (score 1):

That link describes how to do deployment order inside EAR not between two ears.

You should be configuring jboss-all.xml with deployment dependencies.

content should look something like this:

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="app1.ear" />
        <dependency name="app2.ear" />
        <dependency name="app3.ear" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

and add this to all your ears but make sure you don't do cyclic deps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it on Monday. But the link provided does also talk about inter-app dependencies. Quote: _'What if you need configuring the deployment order between two applications, say two EAR files ? then you can use jboss-deployment-structure.xml.'_