# Are inter-ear dependencies in JBoss/Wildfly possible?

Tags: dependencies, classloader, wildfly

According to [Wildfly classloading docs](https://archive.ph/6CLoz), inter-deployment dependencies are possible within an .ear. What about between modules contained in two .ears?

If not, I assume the way to do it would be to use global modules...? Any ideas about the rationale behind such a design decision?

Answer (score 0):

If you read [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) you posted bit more carefully you will see that inter-deployment dependencies are well supported.

```
--- snip ---
    <dependencies>
      <module name="deployment.myarchive.war" />
    </dependencies>
--- snip ---
```

would be example of depending on "myarchive.war" deployment.

also bit be careful when doing this, to also set deployment dependancies otherwise you might run into odd problems on redeploying one of deployments. How to do this was answered in question [JBoss EAR deployment order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959140/jboss-ear-deployment-order/20006937)

Comment: I'm not sure if we understood each other: can you confirm that app.war packaged in app.ear can declare a dependency on app-lib.jar in app-lib.ear, i.e. that app-lib.jar would be on app.war's classpath in spite of being in a different .ear?

Comment: when I try to declare a dependency between myear1.ear and myear2.ear using the suggested approach (module name="deployment.myear2.ear") I get an error while deploying myear1 (myear2 is already deployed): org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: deployment.myear2:main. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: you are probably configuring jboss-deployment-structure.xml wrong, by defining new module with name "deployment.myear2.ear" you should just include it under dependency not defining new module.

Comment: you can also edit your original question with contents of your jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: I am using the dependencies tag: <jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="deployment.myear2.ear" />

Comment: would be good to correct the link as your is broken. Here is archived version: https://archive.ph/6CLoz